# Bootstrap Element Alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and I am trying to discover how to align the object circled in red (in the photograph) to the right.

Here is the original resource files:
https://mega.co.nz/#!HQcTRART

Picture of what I want to achieve:
http://postimg.org/image/n4ke2cfd3/

Comment: Your resource file is encrypted without the password. You may want to post the relevant code here for others to see.

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle so we can help you, and your question can help others on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You should know how Bootstrap works.

- Bootstrap uses a grid layout. The outermost `div` must have a `.container` class.
- Inside `.container`, you can have as many rows. Every row must have a `row` class.
- Every column in bootstrap **must** be inside a `.row`.
  Bootstrap supports 12 columns layout, so when you split into `x` columns, the sum of all column widths must equal to 12.
  For eg: `col-sm-9` and `col-sm-3`. Therefore 9 + 3 = 12

Run the code below and click **Full Screen**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">  <!-- container -->
  <div class="row">       <!-- row -->
    <div class="col-sm-9">   <!-- column -->      
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Doe</td>
            <td>john@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Mary</td>
            <td>Moe</td>
            <td>mary@example.com</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>July</td>
            <td>Dooley</td>
            <td>july@example.com</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">  <!-- column -->
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div> 
 </div>
```